# How to add a custom view in Suite Crm 8.0?

Tags: angular, crm, suitecrm

Need some help with creating custom view in 8.0 like in 7.0. I've already setup everything from herehttps://docs.suitecrm.com/8.x/developer/extensions/frontend/examples/

I've already created extension for my views. But i can't understand how to override view only for my module.